# Use #pragma pack with #define on Borland C++

Tags: c++, c++builder, pragma, borland-c++

I am trying to pack some structs with Borland C++Builder (XE6) (in the future: bcc).

I am using a library which uses the following construct to create structs:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #define PACKED_BEGIN __pragma(pack(push, 1))
    #define PACKED 
    #define PACKED_END __pragma(pack(pop))
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    #define PACKED_BEGIN
    #define PACKED  __attribute__((__packed__))
    #define PACKED_END
#endif


PACKED_BEGIN
struct PACKED {
    short someSampleShort;
    char sampleByte;
    int sampleInteger;
} structType_t;
PACKED_END
```

The bcc compiler does not like the MSC `__pragma`, and does not like preprocessor directives inside of macros although it is described on [their website](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Define):

```
#define GETSTD #include <stdio.h>
```

My Question is: Is there any possibility to use this construct with the Borland Compiler for packing a struct *without* using:

```
#pragma pack(1)
```

to pack every struct?

Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: You may still use `#include "packed_begin.h"` and `#include "packed_end.h"` (without guards)

Comment: Thanks for your Comment, but i cant use #include in a macro because borland does not support this. I could rewrite the Library, but i was hoping for a possibility with macros

Comment: @user2358582 And well it should not, it's not legal C++. I believe Jarod meant you could *replace* the macro lines with that.

Comment: Yeah, i just thought there would be a possibility for not _editing_ the library files. I just could do preg_replace, but when the library gets updated, i have to do this again. With macros, i just can use the new files and it will still be compilable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you stated, C++Builder does not support preprocessor statements inside of macros.  This is documented on Embarcadero's site:

[#define (C++)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Define)

> After each individual macro expansion, a further scan is made of the newly expanded text. This allows for the possibility of nested macros: The expanded text can contain macro identifiers that are subject to replacement. **However, if the macro expands into what looks like a preprocessing directive, the directive will not be recognized by the preprocessor.**

The reason for that is because the `#` character inside of a macro is reserved for the preprocessor's *stringizing operator*.

Some compilers, including MSVC, get around that restriction with the `__pragma()` compiler extension, or the C99/C++x0 `_Pragma()` extension.  C++Builder's **Windows 32bit** compiler  does not support either of those.  However, its **Windows 64bit** and **mobile** compilers (which are all based on clang and support C++11) *DO* support both of them.  So you can add support for those compilers in the macros like this:

```
#if defined(__BORLANDC__)
    #if defined(__clang__)
        #define PACKED_BEGIN __pragma(pack(push, 1))
        #define PACKED 
        #define PACKED_END __pragma(pack(pop))
    #else
        #error Cannot define PACKED macros for this compiler
    #endif
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define PACKED_BEGIN __pragma(pack(push, 1))
    #define PACKED 
    #define PACKED_END __pragma(pack(pop))
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    #define PACKED_BEGIN
    #define PACKED  __attribute__((__packed__))
    #define PACKED_END
#else
    #error PACKED macros are not defined for this compiler
#endif
```

If you want to support the C++Builder **Windows 32bit** compiler, you will have to move the logic into .h files that use `#pragma` for it, and then you can `#include` those files where needed (at least until the compiler is updated to support clang/C++11 - which Embarcadero is currently working on):

pack1_begin.h:

```
#if defined(__BORLANDC__)
    #define PACKED_BEGIN
    #define PACKED 
    #define PACKED_END
    #pragma pack(push, 1)
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define PACKED_BEGIN __pragma(pack(push, 1))
    #define PACKED 
    #define PACKED_END __pragma(pack(pop))
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    #define PACKED_BEGIN
    #define PACKED  __attribute__((__packed__))
    #define PACKED_END
#else
    #error PACKED macros are not defined for this compiler
#endif
```

pack_end.h:

```
#if defined(__BORLANDC__)
    #pragma pack(pop)
#endif
```

Then you can do this:

```
#include "pack1_begin.h"
PACKED_BEGIN
struct PACKED {
    short someSampleShort;
    char sampleByte;
    int sampleInteger;
} structType_t;
PACKED_END
#include "pack_end.h"
```

If you take this approach, you can just drop `PACKED_BEGIN`/`PACKED_END` altogether:

pack1_begin.h:

```
#if defined(__BORLANDC__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define PACKED
    #pragma pack(push, 1)
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
    #define PACKED  __attribute__((__packed__))
#else
    #error PACKED macro is not defined for this compiler
#endif
```

pack_end.h:

```
#if defined(__BORLANDC__) || defined(_MSC_VER)
    #pragma pack(pop)
#endif
```

```
#include "pack1_begin.h"
struct PACKED {
    short someSampleShort;
    char sampleByte;
    int sampleInteger;
} structType_t;
#include "pack_end.h"
```

Comment: I'd just add that a conforming C++ compiler *cannot* support directives in macro replacement. C++11 16.34./3: "The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing
directive even if it resembles one, ..."

Answer (score 0):

The standard offers one extra alternative for writing pragmas: the `_Pragma` operator:

```
#define PACKED_BEGIN _Pragma("pack(push, 1)")
#define PACKED 
#define PACKED_END _Pragma("pack(pop)")
```

If the Borland compiler supports it, it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer, but unfortunately the Borland compiler (my version) does not support _Pragma.

Comment: @user2358582: C++Builder's 32bit compiler does not, but its 64bit and mobile compilers do.